# jQuery .remove() doesn't fire in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Who can explain this, please?

In my function, I use `.remove()` to remove one row of a `<select>` box (I mean to remove an `<option>`) but why doesn't it work?

In FF it looks good, but in IE8 ... fail.

Let's see an example:

```
<form name="test">
```

I have two `<select>` boxes, the first is:

```
<select id='car1' name='car1' onchange='car_remove();'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and the second is:

```
<select id='car2' name='car2'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</form>
```

including this tiny JavaScript function (with `jquery.js` include script in header):

```
function car_remove()
{
  car1_selected = document.test.car1.value;
  $("#car2 option[value="+ car1_selected +"]").remove();
}
```

Comment: What's your code?  Where's your JSFiddle?  Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8zpT/1/

Comment: @lovepong:  You don't need inline JavaScript anymore... you're using jQuery now!  Remove this: `onchange=` and add this to your jQuery functions:  `$('#car1').change(function (){ //stuff_to_do// });`

Comment: @sparky672: I tried to use you solution but it still not working.

Comment: @lovepong:  That's not my solution to your problem. That's a general recommendation regarding inline code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have IE8 to test, but a couple of things might be your problem:

1) The jquery value selector should be in quotes. Change

`$("#car2 option[value="+ car1_selected +"]").remove();`

to

`$("#car2 option[value='"+ car1_selected +"']").remove();`

Note the addition of single quotes in this example (you can also use escaped double quotes).

2) Get in the habit of using the full javascript selector (or jquery equivalent):

`car1_selected = document.test.car1.value;`

should be

```
 car1_selected = document.getElementById("car1").value;
```

In fact, this might be your problem, as 'test' isn't actually an id, but a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function car_remove()
{
  // car1_selected = document.test.car1.value; *Don't use this its a plain javascript*
  // use this. Always try to use jQuery API's instead of conventional JS
  car1_selected =  $('#car1 option[selected]').val();
  $("#car1 option[value="+ car1_selected +"]").remove();
}
```